# Do services such as exchanges offer the participation in mining pools?

Tags: mining-pools

I am studying the structure of mining pools and their participants with on-chain data from GBQ. I noticed that several mining pools use proxy addresses (by combining and filtering for different figures) that forward the mined ether to the participating miners (EOAs).

However, some addresses, that are not proxy addresses according to my heuristic, seem to exhibit a similar behaviour: they send their Ether to many different EOAs and the value of Ether in each transaction is similar to that of proxy address transactions. Is there any other way how people can get money from mining pools without directly being related to that pool?

These are the addresses I was talking about (Some of them even receive Ether from two different Pools, so they cannot be proxy addresses specific to a mining pool):

0x3598ac8dffa22994f0b18087035647c7a09fc389,
0xe8c8e1291ed1949da844b38ff1860a6a4c96e459, 0x57efa1377ef6c0363327ee6cffe46926e5fb682b,
0x1670f6ceaea120fe4e72c9edba3883ae7941401c,
0x7f01921af6dbcf81086c5cf88aa7c93f665278